# No android 8 o Service para e não reinicializa quando a Activity encerra

Tags: android, android-service

Estou testando um service mas quando a activity é encerrada o serviço para
temporariamente, em seguida o service tenta reiniciar, é chamado o método onCreate mas onDestroy é chamado na sequencia e o serviço para definitivamente.

Estou executando em dois dispositivos físicos, o problema ocorre no android 8 no android 6 o serviço consegue reinicializar.

Não estou conseguindo identificar se o problema está na execução a partir
do AndroidStudio (debug), no android 8 ou no dispositivo.

Também não consigo verificar se ocorreu alguma exceção na execução
do serviço porque a instância do app foi encerrada na IDE.

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <service
            android:name="app.service.CServiceMain"
            android:exported="false"
            android:enabled="true">
        </service>
```

CServiceMain.java

```
public class CServiceMain extends Service
{

  private CCounterWorker worker;

  @Override
  public void onCreate()
  {
    super.onCreate();

    CMessage.debug(getClass(),"onCreate");

    worker = new CCounterWorker();
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
  {
    CMessage.debug(getClass(),"onStartCommand");

    new Thread(worker).start();

    return START_STICKY;
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
  {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy()
  {
    CMessage.debug(getClass(),"onDestroy");

    worker.stop = true;
  }

  //-----------------------------------

  public class CCounterWorker implements Runnable
  {
    public boolean stop;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      int i = 0;
      while (!stop) {
        i++;
        CMessage.debug(getClass(),"count " + i);
        CCommon.sleep(1000);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Inicialização do serviço

```
startService(new Intent("contexto",CServiceMain.class));
```

Logcat

```
>>>> Serviço iniciado a partir da activity 

            2018-12-06 17:08:25.902 14321-14321/com.neoporto.elegal CServiceMain: onCreate 
            2018-12-06 17:08:25.904 14321-14321/com.neoporto.elegal CServiceMain: onStartCommand
            2018-12-06 17:08:25.906 14321-14533/com.neoporto.elegal CCounterWorker: count 1
            2018-12-06 17:08:26.906 14321-14533/com.neoporto.elegal CCounterWorker: count 2
            2018-12-06 17:08:27.907 14321-14533/com.neoporto.elegal CCounterWorker: count 3
            2018-12-06 17:08:28.908 14321-14533/com.neoporto.elegal CCounterWorker: count 4
            2018-12-06 17:08:29.909 14321-14533/com.neoporto.elegal CCounterWorker: count 5

>>>> Aqui a activity é encerrada e o serviço tenta restartar

            2018-12-06 17:08:33.582 14546-14546/com.neoporto.elegal CServiceMain: onCreate 
            2018-12-06 17:08:33.583 14546-14546/com.neoporto.elegal CServiceMain: onDestroy
```

Answer (score 1):

Isso tem a ver com as restrições que o Android 8 impõe, entre outras, ao uso de serviços, quando a aplicação está em *background*.

As restrições visam diminuir o consumo da bateria e melhorar a performance geral do dispositivo.

Essas restrições, por padrão, só são aplicadas a aplicações com `android:targetSdkVersion=26` ou superior. No entanto, o usuário pode activar essas restrições para qualquer aplicação, na tela de "Configurações" do dispositivo.

A abordagem a aplicar para a migração ao Android 8 depende da aplicação e do propósito do serviço.

Para mais informações consultar a documentação:

- [Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes).
- [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background).